# Docker -это слабая vmware?

Tags: docker, vmware

Я сразу предупреждаю. Я плохо знаю все тонкости Docker, но кое-что понимаю в виртуализации. И что я вижу. Я могу ошибаться, но docker это просто подобие vmware.
В чем ценность docker? Что в нем такого чего нет в vmware. Про "бесплатность" песня не интересна.

Comment: vmware - это прям полноценная ОС, на которой установлено все что нужно и ненужно. а докер контейнер содержит только то, что нужно для запуска, ну допустим, nodejs сервера или чего-то другого. сам контейнер - это какой-то изолированный кусок ОЗУ, CPU и HDD, к которым имеют доступ только определнные процессы. это не ОС

Comment: Docker — это вообще не виртуализация.

Comment: Запуская виртуалку vmware и других средств виртуализации вы запускаете в ней полноценное ядро ОC, которое пытается работать как обычно с железом на прямую. При этом на уровне процессора все подозрительные операции блокируются и даются на обработку коду виртуальной машины. Это достаточно медленно. Кроме того сама ОС внутри ВМ занимает кучу ОЗУ. А докер, это не система виртуализации, все операции выполняет ядро основной ОС. Дочерняя ОС не нужна, меньше затраты памяти и накладные расходы...

Comment: Все что делает докер, используя средства ОС изолирует выполняемые процессы, что бы они не имели доступ к другим процессам в системе. Так что докер это не слабая vmware, а гораздо более быстрая vmware, без vm :)

Comment: Daniel, огромное спасибо. Это скорее как  LPAR в AIX

Answer (score 2):

Докер - это способ запускать обычный процесс (или несколько) операционной системы, но в изолированном окружении. Это такой `chroot` не стероидах. Изоляция осуществляется используя функциональность, которую предоставляет сам линукс, а именно [пространства имен](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces).

Когда запускается контейнер, то у него свой набор примотнированных файловых систем, свои пользователи и группы ОС, свое пространство PID-ов, свои TCP порты, сетевые интерфейсы и т.п.